# Typical cluster size in ising model

Tags: ising-model

What is typical cluster size in two dimensional ising model. By cluster size I mean size of domain. 
Can I call correlation length of spin-spin correlation to be typical size of clusters.

Is the text written below is correct?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "cluster", or actually by "domain". Actually, at equilibrium in the two-dimensional Ising model, when $T<T_c$, typical configurations in the $+$ phase look like a "sea" of $+$ spins with "islands of $-$ spins (themselves possibly containing "lakes of $+$ spins, etc.):

[image: A typical configuration of the 2d Ising model below the critical temperature]

(In this picture, $-$ spins are in black, $+$ spins in white. Each connected black object is a cluster.)

What you are saying is correct if by cluster size you mean the average diameter of a such an "island" of $-$ spins in the $+$ phase (that is, a connected set of vertices at which the spins are all equal to $-1$).

[If by domain/cluster, you mean something like Weiss domains, then the latter do not exist in the Ising model (even though you might see something similar in simulations if the system has not reached equilibrium).]

Assuming that you mean the average diameter of an island of $-$ in the $+$ phase: if $D$ is the average diameter and $\xi$ the correlation length associated to the 2-point function, then there exist two constants $C, c>0$ such that $c\xi\leq D \leq C \xi$ at all temperature $T<T_c$. In particular, they scale in the same way as $T$ approaches $T_c$.

Note that this is not true in higher dimensions (at least not with a naive notion of clusters, as the one given above), since $-$ spins percolate in the $+$ phase when $T$ is close enough to $T_c$ (see for instance [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01009363)), so that the naive cluster size is infinite. You can still make this equivalence work in this case in various ways. For instance, you can define "clusters" as the clusters in the Fortuin-Kasteleyn representation (with which you might be familiar through its use in the [Swendsen-Wang algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swendsen%E2%80%93Wang_algorithm); it is also often called the [random-cluster representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_cluster_model)).

Comment: Note that I am not sure I understood your question: maybe you were thinking of the model *above the critical temperature*? If yes, I can update this answer.

Comment: Yes. You gave proper definition of what I was thinking. Just two more thing: 1. If $c\zeta <D<C\zeta $, then as we go near critical temperature, the D (average size of - in + sea) should be diverging, right? 2. What happens above $T>T_c$?

Comment: I also updated question. Can you have look?

Comment: @KartikChhajed What you write is correct. You might be more careful in the last paragraph. The critical behavior might not depend on "details" of the model (underlying lattice, precise range of interactions, etc.), its does depend on general features (short or long-range interactions, symmetry group, etc.).